# Parabola tangent to four lines

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Suppose that in the affine plane R^2 four lines are given, with the property that no two are parallel and no three are concurrent. Show that there exists a unique parabola tangent to each of the four lines.

My attempts: I want to extend the affine plane R^2 to a projective plane PR^2 and consider the dual space of PR^2. But 'parallel' and 'being a parabola' are not projective properties, so things become difficult.

Comment: First thought: The four lines cut the plane in 11 parts, 8 of which are unbound. And only one of those 8 is delimited by all four lines. So the parabola can only fit in this one part of a plane.